# Horizontal scroll bar appears when it doesn't need to

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, horizontal-scroll-bar

The code sample below is visible in its entirety, yet a horizontal scroll bar appears.

```
012345678-012345678-012345678-012345678-012345678-012345678-012345678-012345678-01
```

Can that be prevented?

Comment: FWIW - I don't get the scrollbar in FF4 on Win7

Comment: @squillman: I'm using FireFox 4.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: As am I *shrug*

Answer (score 15):

No.

The last pixel of the last `1` is not visible.
You need the scrollbar to see the full glory of this pixel.

Comment: be nice if it word wrapped.

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  Word-wrapped code is very annoying.

Comment: It would be especially annoying when diagnosing newline-related syntax errors in questions.

Comment: true, i didnt think of that

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a scrollbar at all in FireFox 4.01. If you're still seeing it, it must be a cross-browser issue.

**EDIT:**

Went home and checked it in Safari (OSX Snow Leopard), with the default font size. The scrollbar is there.

Comment: I'm using FireFox 4.0.1.

Comment: I see it in FireFox 3.6

Comment: Rendering depends on fonts and font-size prefs, here and anywhere else.

Comment: I can't manage to rewrite my comment into a satisfactory answer (or be bothered to spend a lot of time). SLaks's is okay if you don't mind.